# place 2 divs inside a wrapper of different width without fixing the width of the second div

Tags: css, html, width, alignment

i have my html something like this...

```
<div class = "content">
    <div class = "folder-list">
    </div>
    <div class = "message-list">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now my **folder-list** div size is 160px. Now I want the **message-list** div to take rest of the width of the content class which is set to 100%(width of the content). I dont want to fix the width for **message-list** in the CSS. How can  I achieve that?

I have added *float:left* property to both the divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write like this:

```
.folder-list{
 width:160px;
 float:left;
}
.message-list{
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/BB9w6/

Comment: but according to the natural property of divs if i do not set the width, it only takes the size of the content right? i want it to take the rest of the space of the content div all the time..even if the any content is not there.. something like gmail. it shows u the folders list and then it takes the rest of the width to show the messages

Comment: div is a block element & block naturally takes his parent width.But if you define display:inline, float & position:absolute; to it. Then it only takes the size of the content.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

css code:

```
.folder-list{
    width: 160px;
    background:orange;
    float:left;
}
.message-list{
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
}
```

html code:

```
<div class = "content">
    <div class = "folder-list">
    Test1
    </div>
    <div class = "message-list">
    Test2

    </div>
</div>
```